# Cardinality of all injective functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

What is the cardianlity of: $$ A = \left\{ f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R} : \text{f is injective} \right\} $$

Trying to prove it using Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem, I have the obvious side:
$$A \subseteq f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$$

Hence,
$$\left|A\right| \le \aleph$$

I need to find an injection from a set with cardinality of $\aleph$ to $A$, but couldn't think of a proper one. It's tricky.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Zero nothing nadda.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87902/problems-about-countability-related-to-function-spaces and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144186/set-of-all-injective-functions-a-to-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** Prove that $\{f\in A\mid\operatorname{range}(f)\subseteq\Bbb N\}$ has size $\aleph$.

Comment: Or just ask it the other way round (injections N -> R).

Comment: Right. I'll claim it was a typo!

Comment: @Elimination: Alright, a different hint, then.

Comment: Can I get an hint for the hint? :)

Comment: @Elimination: Certainly. For every infinite set $D\subseteq\Bbb N$ consider the function which fixes pointwise $\Bbb N\setminus D$, partitions $D$ into pairs and switches all those pairs.

Comment: I dont get it :|

Comment: @Elimination: Pick any bijection $h\colon\Bbb{N\to N}$ without fixed points (for example, exchange the $n$-th even number with the $n$-th odd number). Now given an infinite subset of $A\subseteq\Bbb N$, consider the function $f_A\colon\Bbb{N\to N}$ which does this: $f_A(n)=n$ whenever $n\notin A$; if $n=a_k$, then $f_A(n)=a_{h(k)}$. (Where $a_k$ is a fixed enumeration of $A$, e.g. the one which respects the natural order of the natural numbers.) Now show that $f_A$ is injective, and that $A\neq B$ implies $f_A\neq f_B$. And how many infinite subsets does $\Bbb N$ have?

Answer (score 3):

For each $a\in(0,1)$ we'll define a function $f(n) = a+n$. $f$ is clearly in $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ and since it's monotone it is also injective. Moreover, if $a_1\ne a_2$ then $f_1(n) \ne f_2(n)$.

Hence, the set of all functions described is subset of $A$ and it's cardinality is $\left|\left(0,1\right)\right| = \aleph$

Comment: Yeah, that's also works. (Simpler than my hint; although proving that the set of injections from $\Bbb N$ to itself has size $\aleph$ gives you more information.)