# cardinality of the set of $ \varphi: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that $\varphi$ is an increasing sequence

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I know that the set of functions $ f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is uncountable, but what if we consider only $f$ such that $f$ is increasing? I want to know if this set is countable D: and also the case of bijective and increasing (clearly if the firstone holds then this too). I think that it could be possible that it's countable

Comment: A slight modification of this question (non-decreasing vs. increasing) was also asked as one part of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87902/problems-about-countability-related-to-function-spaces).

Comment: The "real" question has been answered already, but since you also asked about "bijective and increasing", notice that the only bijective increasing function $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is the identity function.

Answer (score 12):

This is essentially reversing Brian M. Scott's initial argument...

Let $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}\uparrow}$ denote the family of strictly increasing functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.  Given any function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ define $\Phi ( f ) : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ by  $$\Phi ( f ) ( n ) = \sum_{i=0}^n ( f(i) + 1 )$$ Then $\Phi ( f )$ is strictly increasing, and the mapping $f \mapsto \Phi ( f )$ is one-to-one.

Therefore, $| \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} | \leq | \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}\uparrow} |$. A quick application of the Cantor–Bernstein–Schröder Theorem then yields $| \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}\uparrow} | = | \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} | = 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @einpoklum: It's customary to make such additions in the comments. Not into the answers.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: That's not what the FAQ says ([Other people can edit my posts?](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#editing)) "If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you."

Comment: @Dietrich: The FAQ cannot be changed per site; but the mentality and behavior of the community *does* differ from one site to another. I want to think that in my nearly thousand days of activity I learned a few things about the community norm here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I would think very-high-rep users would in general be more accepting of these kinds of edits... or am I wrong?

Comment: @einpoklum: I don't follow this logic.

Comment: "$\Phi ( f ) ( n ) = \sum_{i=0}^n ( f(i) + 1 )$" does this actually sum all the sequences after adding 1 to each one so it will equal to a new 'combined' increasing sequence ? Can you also explain a bit about how to apply CBS here ?

Comment: @GinKin: (I'm not exactly sure of the first part of your comment.) As a preliminary note, be warned that I include $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$. I set up the function $\Phi$ so that (1) it always outputs a strictly increasing function, and (2) it is one-to-one. Note that I cannot simply take $\Phi(f)(n)=\sum_{i=0}^nf(i)$, since if $f(n+1)=0$ then $\Phi(f)(n)=\Phi(f)(n+1)$. The "$+1$" is there to ensure that $\Phi(f)$ is _strictly_ increasing. For one-to-one, note that given $\Phi(f)$ we can simply reverse the process to get $f$ back: $f(0) = \Phi(f)(0)-1$; $f(1) = \Phi(f)(1)-f(0)-2$, etc. [cont...]

Comment: [...inued] For CBS, note that the function $\Phi$ witnesses that $| \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} | \leq | \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}\uparrow} |$.  As $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}\uparrow} \subseteq \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ we clearly have that $| \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}\uparrow} | \leq |\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}|$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In the first part I asked what does the sum actually do here, does it sum all the sequences so each $f(i)$ represents a sequence ?

Comment: @GinKin: Sorry about this long delay; was busy/sleeping.  Okay, so $f$ itself is a sequence in $\mathbb{N}$ (or, equivalently, a function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$).  So $f(i)$ is just a natural number, meaning that we are just summing up naturar numbers.

Answer (score 8):

Let $e_1,e_2,e_3,\dots$ be **any** sequence of $0$'s and/or $1$'s. Let $a_1=1$ and $a_{i+1}=a_i+e_i+1$.

This shows that there are at least $c$ increasing sequences. So there are exactly $c$.

Comment: Why do you take $e_i$ to be binary sequences when the question asks about all increasing sequences of natural numbers ?

Comment: @GinKin:   From **any** binary sequence, we produce an increasing sequence of natural numbers. It is clear that two distinct binary sequences produce distinct increasing sequences. So we have produced an injective mapping from binary sequences to increasing sequences. To put it another way, the set of binary sequences has the same cardinality as a **subset** of the increasing sequences. Thus the cardinality of the set of increasing sequences is at least as big as the cardinality of the set of binary sequences. The set of binary sequences has cardinality $c$. (Cont)

Comment: (Cont) So the set of increasing sequences has cardinality $\ge c$. But the set of increasing sequences also has cardinality $\le c$. Therefore the vardinality is exactly $c$.

Answer (score 7):

It's uncountable. Suppose that $f_n$ is a sequence of strictly increasing sequences, let $g(0)=f_0(0)+1$; and $g(n+1)=\max\{g(n)+1, f_{n+1}(n+1)+1\}$. Clearly $g$ is not one of the $f_n$'s.

Comment: How does uncountability follow from this?

Comment: @GitGud: The same way it would follow from any standard diagonalization argument. Any function from $\Bbb N$ onto this set cannot be surjective.

Comment: This doesn't answer what the cardinality is, or am I missing something ?

Comment: @GinKin: That is correct. But if you read the actual question, then OP wanted to know "that this set is countable". I answered with a way to prove that it is not.

Comment: The title actually asks for the cardinality. Also my question from yesterday was marked as duplicate of this one even though mine was asking for the cardinality and not if it's countable.

Comment: @GinKin: Yes. The title says cardinality, and the question says "uncountable". There are other answers which answer both the title and the body of the question, and therefore answer your question as well.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the set of strictly increasing functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$: then $|\mathscr{F}|=2^\omega=|\wp(\Bbb N)|$, so $\mathscr{F}$ is certainly uncountable. One way to see this is to construct a bijection between $\mathscr{F}$ and ${}^{\Bbb N}\Bbb N$, the set of all functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$. This isn’t too hard.

Define a function $\mathscr{F}\to{}^{\Bbb N}\Bbb N:f\mapsto\hat f$ as follows: let $f\in\mathscr{F}$, and define $\hat f$ by setting $\hat f(0)=0$ and $\hat f(k)=f(k)-f(k-1)-1$ for $k>0$. It’s easy to check that this map is a bijection, so $|\mathscr{F}|=\left|{}^{\Bbb N}\Bbb N\right|$, which you probably already know is $2^\omega=|\wp(\Bbb N)|$.

**Added:** The inverse map is easy enough to write down as well: if $f\in{}^{\Bbb N}\Bbb N$, let

$$g:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N:n\mapsto n+\sum_{k\le n}f(k)\;.$$

then $$\hat g(n)=\left(n+\sum_{k\le n}f(k)\right)-\left((n-1)+\sum_{k\le n-1}f(k)\right)-1=f(n)\;,$$

i.e., $\hat g=f$.

Comment: May I ask, why do you use the notation $^\Bbb N\Bbb N$?

Comment: It is written there

Comment: @Ilya: Because ${}^AB$ is a standard notation for the set of functions from $A$ to $B$, one that can’t be confused with exponentiation. That isn’t a problem here, but it is when you’re talking about cardinal numbers $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ and want to distinguish the set of functions ${}^\kappa\lambda$ from the cardinal number $\lambda^\kappa$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I see, I thought $B^A$ is a standard one, like $\Bbb R^{[0,\infty)}$ in stochastic processes usually denotes the space of real-valued functions on the domain $[0,\infty)$

Comment: @Ilya: They’re both standard; it’s probably only people working in somewhat set-theoretic areas who have to worry about the potential confusion and who end up using ${}^AB$.

Comment: What does $k$ stands for here?

Comment: @Ilya, looks like Brian hasn't logged in in a long time, do you know what does the $k$ stands for in his answer ?

Comment: @GinKin: as far as I can follow, Brian defines a transformation $\hat$ from the collection of function $\mathscr F$ to another collection $^\Bbb N\Bbb N$. Given any $f\in \mathscr F$, we hence obtain that $\hat f\in ^\Bbb N\Bbb N$ or equivalently $\hat f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$. Now, to define $\hat f$ as a function you need to define it for any natural number $k\in \Bbb N$ - that was is done in the answer, $k$ is just a generic argument of $\hat f$.

Answer (score 3):

A nice idea how to prove this was given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87902/problems-about-countability-related-to-function-spaces/87905#87905) by [Srivatsan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13425/srivatsan). I am reposting it here since the other question addresses several points, so this might be easily missed among solutions of other parts of that question.

---

Consider only maps $\varphi \colon \mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ such that $k$ is mapped either to $2k$ or to $2k+1$.

Every such map is increasing.

We have two possibilities how to choose $\varphi(k)$ for each $k$, so there is $2^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak c$ such functions. (To make this argument more rigorous, you can show that you can obtain for each element of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ a different function of this form.)