# $\Bbb {R^R}$ equinumerous to $\{f\in\Bbb{R^R}\mid f\text{ surjective}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In an introductory course on axiomatic set theory, I am asked whether $\Bbb {R^R}$ is equinumerous to the set of all *surjective* functions in $\Bbb{R^R}$ (say $\mathcal S$). Because of the evocative nature of the question, I assume this to be true. However, I have not been able to prove it.

Using Schroeder-Bernstein, we would need to find an injection from $\Bbb{R^R}\rightarrow\mathcal S$, but I don't have the slightest idea how we could get this. In a similar question involving $\Bbb N$ instead of $\Bbb R$, this could be done (quite) easily since we could speak about sequences, but that won't help here.

Comment: Finding an injection from $\mathcal{S}$ to $\Bbb{R}^\Bbb{R}$ is easy - just consider the inclusion map. I guess that you means the reverse.

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely correct, I will edit it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For given function $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, define
$$\phi_f (x) = \begin{cases} \tan (\pi x/2) & \text{if }-1<x<1 \\ f(\tan(\pi (x-2)/2)) & \text{if }1<x<3 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$
You can check that the map $f\mapsto \phi_f$ is one-to-one. Also, $\phi_f$ is a surjection to $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Can this also be expanded so that $\phi_f$ is a bijection?

Comment: @konewka Did you mean a function $\phi_f \in \Bbb{R}^\Bbb{R}$ or the function maps $f$ to $\phi_f$?

Comment: The function $\phi_f$, so in my original question, replacing $\mathcal S$ by the set of *bijective* functions. Or would those two not be equinumerous?

Comment: @konewka You may construct it. The set of all bijection from the reals to itself is equinumerous to $\Bbb{R}^\Bbb{R}$, but I didn't get how to construct the bijection explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

It suffices to divide $\mathbb R$ into two sets $A$ and $B$ such that $|A|=|B|=|\mathbb R|$.

This means you have some bijection $\varphi$ from $A$ to $B$. I.e., you have pairs $a\in A$ and $\varphi(a)\in B$

Using these two subsets you can construct bijections $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by choosing some pairs, which you swap, and letting other elements in place.

More formally, if $C\subseteq A$, then we can define $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ as
$$
f(x)=
  \begin{cases}
    \varphi(x) & x\in C, \\
    \varphi^{-1}(x) & x\in \varphi[C], \\
    x & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
$$

In this way we get a different bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ for every subsets of $A$. So there is at least as many bijections from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ as the number of subsets of $A$, which is $2^{\mathfrak c}$.

If we denote by $\mathcal S$ the set of all surjections and $\mathcal B$ the set of all bijections (from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$), we have
$$2^{\mathfrak c} \le |\mathcal B| \le |\mathcal S| \le |\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}|=\mathfrak c^{\mathfrak c}=2^{\mathfrak c}.$$

---

You can also have a look at this post on MO, which deals with bijections on arbitrary set: [Cardinality of the permutations of an infinite set](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27785/cardinality-of-the-permutations-of-an-infinite-set/). In fact, [Robin Chapman's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/27788/8250) posted there gives basically the same argument as I gave above. It should be mentioned that if we do the same argument for arbitrary set, we would use Axiom of Choice to get the decomposition $X=A\cup B$ such that $|X|=|A|=|B|$. Some details about role of AC here are give in [Andreas Blass' answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/86594/8250) to the same post.

There were also several posts about cardinality of the set of all bijections from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$. Some of the arguments given there can be used also for $\mathbb R$:

- [Cardinality of the set of bijective functions on $\mathbb{N}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367194/cardinality-of-the-set-of-bijective-functions-on-mathbbn)
- [Problems about Countability related to Function Spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87902/problems-about-countability-related-to-function-spaces)
- [An easy proof of the uncountability of bijections on natural numbers?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29475/an-easy-proof-of-the-uncountability-of-bijections-on-natural-numbers) at MathOverflow.

And you could find other similar questions.

**Remark on use of Axiom of Choice.** In connection with [another question on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3367572/can-the-set-of-endomorphisms-of-mathbbr-have-cardinality-strictly-betwe), it might be also interesting whether we can do this in ZF. It's not difficult to see that we might replace $\mathbb R$ with $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$. (Since we can write down an explicit bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$.) If we choose $A=(0,\infty)$, $B=(-\infty,0)$ and $\varphi(x)=-x$, then the above construction gives an *explicit* bijection $f\colon \mathbb R\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ for every $C\subseteq A$.